# How to properly set a conditional statement in sequence?

Tags: webmethods

I'm trying to set a conditional statement in web methods. I think I'm on the right path and missing couple small steps trying to get it done.

So my branch is going is going through a path. /barcode
Then the sequence's job is to keep the length 18 or below characters. My label in the sequence looks like this: (%barcode%)<=18.

This flow is getting skipped over.

Comment: what is the value of variable `barcode` is it the length itself? or you are trying to find out the length of the value of `barcode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to find the length of the value in `barcode`. Use this service `pub.string:length` in a map step to find out the length and then use that length for the comparison.